# Xpath Relative path for an attribute

Tags: xpath

Here is my element:

```
<a href="http://testwebsite.com/id/TestID/edit/">
```

TestID is the variable which keeps changing dependent on the user.
I need to find one possibility for this:

```
//a[@href='http://testwebsite.com/id/']
```

The only problem with the line right above is it's direct, not relative. How do I do an all but on the end of the link?

Comment: `How do I do an all but on the end of the link?` - Please elaborate.

Comment: For example, as long as "http://testwebsite.com/id/" is that. Then It'll find the attribute. Currently the TestID variable changes for every user (for this site) but everything after "ID" does not matter. Just as long as "http://testwebsite.com/id/" is the start of the href.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://testwebsite.com/id/')]
```

This `XPath` should match required anchor element regardless of `TestID` value